# Proper JSON format with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I probably have a simple problem with generating proper JSON output in PHP. I use the following code to collect the relevant data form a mysql database.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "civitas");
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();
 }
$events = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT title_hu FROM `events`")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $events[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($events, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

The code generates the following output:

```
[
    {
        "title_hu": "Zr\u00ednyi napok s",
        "created_at": "2015-08-31 16:26:23"
    },
    {
        "title_hu": "Persona Non Grata 25. sz\u00fclet\u00e9snapi koncert",
        "created_at": "2015-08-31 18:12:25"
    },
    {
        "title_hu": "Bek\u00f6lt\u00f6z\u0151s buli",
        "created_at": "2015-08-31 18:22:29"
    },
    {
        "title_hu": "as",
        "created_at": "2015-08-31 18:29:13"
    },
    {
        "title_hu": "dddd",
        "created_at": "2015-08-31 18:29:58"
    }
]
```

But for the tool I use the format should be this:

```
{
    "events":[{
            "title_hu":"Teszt hír",
            "content":" lorembalblalba ",
            "created_at":"2015-08-31 18:29:58"
        },
        {
            "title_hu":"Teszt hír2",
            "content":" lorembalblalba ",
            "created_at":"2015-08-31 18:29:58"
        },
        {
            "title_hu":"Teszt hír3",
            "content":" lorembalblalba ",
            "created_at":"2015-08-31 18:29:58"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to put the result into another array but in that case the JSON output returns only the first item of the dataset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try with `$events['events'][] = $row;` inside the loop and do not forget to declare `$events['events']` as an array before loop.

Comment: so this `json_encode(array('events'=>$events), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change your query to

```
SELECT title_hu,content,created_at FROM `events`
```

And for creating JSON use

```
$rows = array();// define array
$events = array();// define array
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $events[] = $row;// assign table data to array
    }
$rows['events'] = $events;// assign your table data and array to an empty array
echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);// your final JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "civitas");
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();
}
$events = array('events'=>array());

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT title_hu, content, created_at FROM `events`")) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $events['events'][] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($events, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

This should do the trick.